# Xamarin ToolBarItems Navigation rules

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to add these toolbars to my contentpage, it works if it is the first page of the navigaitionstack. But if I use it as the second, I can't get any menu. How do I get the toolbaritems appear on the IssuePage without making it my starting page?

```
       public partial class IssuesPage : ContentPage
       {     
                var home = new ToolbarItem
                {
                    Text = "Add New",
                    Icon = "Add.png",
                    Order = ToolbarItemOrder.Primary,
                    Priority = 0,
                };
                home.Clicked += this.OnClickNewIssue;
                this.ToolbarItems.Add(home);

                var map = new ToolbarItem
                {
                    Text = "Map",
                    Icon = "map.png",
                    Order = ToolbarItemOrder.Primary,
                    Priority = 0,
                };
                map.Clicked += this.OnClickShowMap;
                this.ToolbarItems.Add(map);


                var loginLocation = new ToolbarItem
                {
                    Text = "Login and Location",
                    Icon = "menu.png",
                    Order = ToolbarItemOrder.Secondary,
                    Priority = 0,
                };
                loginLocation.Clicked += this.OnClickLoginLocation;
                this.ToolbarItems.Add(loginLocation);

                var filter = new ToolbarItem
                {
                    Text = "Filter and Sorting",
                    Icon = "filter.png",
                    Order = ToolbarItemOrder.Secondary,
                    Priority = 1,
                };
                filter.Clicked += this.OnClickSetFilter;
                this.ToolbarItems.Add(filter);
            }
```

Here is the page order later on.

```
   public App()
   {
       Client = new AppIssueClient();
       // The root page of your application
       MainPage = GetMainPage();

   }
  public static Page GetMainPage()
  {
       return new NavigationPage(new IssueCarouselPage(new UIIssueVM(true)));
  }
```

and this is how I go to the IssuePage from the IssueCarosuelPage

```
void OnGoToEventList(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Navigation.PushModalAsync(new IssuesPage(-1));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that using `PushModalAsync` you are pushing an entirely new page on the stack, which replaces not only the `IssueCarouselPage` but even the `NavigationPage` that wraps it. And because of that, you will lose the toolbar functionality. To fix this, do the following:

```
void OnGoToEventList(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(new IssuesPage(-1)));
}
```

Now you will push a new navigation page on the stack, that contains your new `IssuesPage` and the navigation page will provide the toolbar. Alternatively you could use just `PushAsync` for hierarchical navigation:

```
void OnGoToEventList(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Navigation.PushAsync(new IssuesPage(-1));
}
```

Which one you should use depends on your specific use case. There is a very nice comparison of both forms of navigation in [this blog article](http://blog.adamkemp.com/2014/09/navigation-in-xamarinforms_2.html).

Comment: Thanks, that was a great explaniation and link :)

Comment: Glad to help! Happy coding :-)